# Autohotkey hotstring expand w94 to width:94px;?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I do this, given that the number following w could be a variable length? does autohotkey hotstrings support regex or variable pattern matching?

I currenty have w expanding to width:px and the cursor positioned before the px.

`:oR0:w::width:px;{left 3}`

Comment: Which platform and which app are you using?

Comment: windows 7, autohotkey 1.0.48

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `hotstrings( regexStr, expandedStr)` method defined [here](https://github.com/polyethene/autohotkey-scripts/raw/master/Hotstrings.ahk) and add this to the top of the script above the definition of the function:

```
 hotstrings( "w(\d+)\s", "width:%$1%px;" )
```

I've got it working on AutoHotKey 1.0.46.01 on Windows XP.

Comment: That looks promising. I can't get it to work however. I pasted the contents hotstrings.ahk at the bottom of my existing script. Then I put the one line call you've got above at the top of my script. Nothing happens when I type w94 and hit space.

Comment: I think I am missing how to setup the hostrings, I'm finding some info about an .ini file but I don't have an autohotkey.ini file on my machine. Could you clarify how you've got it setup?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I created a new script called `hotstrings.ahk` with the function declaration at the bottom and my 1 line hostring definitions at the top. It works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Moin: Glad it worked for you!